# Subtract rows to display the difference in MySql

Tags: mysql

I created a table where I record daily hour meter readings. I need to subtract the total meter readings from one day to another to display the daily running hours.

here is a DB fiddle what is working for one row: [db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vSM6hA2Wa3cpRJAqEoDMKZ/2)

My table is looking like below:

```
        INSERT INTO `cuidadrun` (`cuidad_id`, `date`, `bc100a`, `bc100b`, `bc100c`, `bc100d`, `bc100e`) VALUES
    (1, '2018-10-18', 500, 500, 500, 500, 500),
    (2, '2018-10-19', 518, 520, 520, 520, 520),
    (3, '2018-10-20', 539, 540, 540, 540, 540),
    (4, '2018-10-21', 558, 560, 560, 560, 560);
    COMMIT;

---

**Query #1**

    SELECT date,
    COALESCE(m1.bc100a - (SELECT m2.bc100a FROM cuidadrun m2 WHERE m2.cuidad_id = m1.cuidad_id - 1), 0) AS diffBC100a 
    FROM cuidadrun m1;
```

Result:

```
| date       | diffBC100a |
| ---------- | ---------- |
| 2018-10-18 | 0          |
| 2018-10-19 | 18         |
| 2018-10-20 | 21         |
| 2018-10-21 | 19         |
```

My goal is to display the daily hours from each meter in a table like below.

```
| date       | diffBC100a | diffBC100b | diffBC100c | diffBC100d | diffBC100e |
| ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 2018-10-18 | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          |
| 2018-10-19 | 18         | 20         | 20         | 20         | 20         |
| 2018-10-20 | 21         | 20         | 20         | 20         | 20         |
| 2018-10-21 | 19         | 20         | 20         | 20         | 20         |
```

I can't work out how I could achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Subquery, I would do a "Self-Left-Join" to a previous `id` value row.

```
SELECT m1.date,
       COALESCE(m1.bc100a - m2.bc100a, 0) AS diffBC100a, 
       COALESCE(m1.bc100b - m2.bc100b, 0) AS diffBC100b, 
       COALESCE(m1.bc100c - m2.bc100c, 0) AS diffBC100c, 
       COALESCE(m1.bc100d - m2.bc100d, 0) AS diffBC100d, 
       COALESCE(m1.bc100e - m2.bc100e, 0) AS diffBC100e
FROM cuidadrun AS m1 
LEFT JOIN cuidadrun AS m2
  ON m2.cuidad_id = m1.cuidad_id - 1 
ORDER BY m1.date
```

---

**Result**

```
| date       | diffBC100a | diffBC100b | diffBC100c | diffBC100d | diffBC100e |
| ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ---------- |
| 2018-10-18 | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          | 0          |
| 2018-10-19 | 18         | 20         | 20         | 20         | 20         |
| 2018-10-20 | 21         | 20         | 20         | 20         | 20         |
| 2018-10-21 | 19         | 20         | 20         | 20         | 20         |
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vSM6hA2Wa3cpRJAqEoDMKZ/3)